# How to translate "front matter"?

Tags: single-word-requests, literature

Many books consist (on the inside, so apart from their cover) of three parts (cf. [Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Book_design&oldid=925166448#Structure):

1. The **"front matter"** a.k.a. **"prelims"**, consisting of title page and if applicable, dedication(s), table of contents, foreword(s), etc.
2. The **"body matter"**, which holds the books actual main content
3. The **"back matter"** or **"end matter"**, consisting of appendices, glossaries, bibliographies, indices, etc.

Sometimes, this terminology is extended to other genres of text, like articles, where the "front matter" may just consist of the preceding summary (if any) or introduction.

**What would be a good Esperanto term to capture the concept of "front matter"?** As Esperanto has its own history of printed books, is there maybe even an already established *presfakvorto* for it?

Comment: In case this helps, the German word for "front matter" seems to be [Titelei](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titelei).

Comment: antaŭaĵoj? antaŭaĵaro?

Answer (score 2):

*libroantaŭo, librokorpo, libromalantaŭo* or ***antaŭparto, ĉefparto, malantaŭparto*** would be my ad-hoc terms. I doubt that type setting related terminologies exist, are in widespread use. Looked into [Terminologia Esperanto-Centro](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminologia_Esperanto-Centro) but did not find anything.